# class NotificationManagerCompat is missing classes

Tags: java, android, import

I clicked on the class NotificationManagerCompat and I cannot find the public methods

```
areNotificationsEnabled()
    getImportance()
```

They are also both the only methods that return variables.  I need to use the method areNotificationsEnabled() does anyone have any ideas how this could be possible?

Currently my import line is as follows 
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

Not sure if it helps for me to post the entire class but here it is

```
    /*
 * Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.support.v4.app;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.DeadObjectException;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Compatibility library for NotificationManager with fallbacks for older platforms.
 *
 * <p>To use this class, call the static function {@link #from} to get a
 * {@link NotificationManagerCompat} object, and then call one of its
 * methods to post or cancel notifications.
 */
public class NotificationManagerCompat {
    private static final String TAG = "NotifManCompat";

    /**
     * Notification extras key: if set to true, the posted notification should use
     * the side channel for delivery instead of using notification manager.
     */
    public static final String EXTRA_USE_SIDE_CHANNEL =
            NotificationCompatJellybean.EXTRA_USE_SIDE_CHANNEL;

    /**
     * Intent action to register for on a service to receive side channel
     * notifications. The listening service must be in the same package as an enabled
     * {@link android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService}.
     */
    public static final String ACTION_BIND_SIDE_CHANNEL =
            "android.support.BIND_NOTIFICATION_SIDE_CHANNEL";

    /**
     * Maximum sdk build version which needs support for side channeled notifications.
     * Currently the only needed use is for side channeling group children before KITKAT_WATCH.
     */
    static final int MAX_SIDE_CHANNEL_SDK_VERSION = 19;

    /** Base time delay for a side channel listener queue retry. */
    private static final int SIDE_CHANNEL_RETRY_BASE_INTERVAL_MS = 1000;
    /** Maximum retries for a side channel listener before dropping tasks. */
    private static final int SIDE_CHANNEL_RETRY_MAX_COUNT = 6;
    /** Hidden field Settings.Secure.ENABLED_NOTIFICATION_LISTENERS */
    private static final String SETTING_ENABLED_NOTIFICATION_LISTENERS =
            "enabled_notification_listeners";
    private static final int SIDE_CHANNEL_BIND_FLAGS;

    /** Cache of enabled notification listener components */
    private static final Object sEnabledNotificationListenersLock = new Object();
    /** Guarded by {@link #sEnabledNotificationListenersLock} */
    private static String sEnabledNotificationListeners;
    /** Guarded by {@link #sEnabledNotificationListenersLock} */
    private static Set<String> sEnabledNotificationListenerPackages = new HashSet<String>();

    private final Context mContext;
    private final NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    /** Lock for mutable static fields */
    private static final Object sLock = new Object();
    /** Guarded by {@link #sLock} */
    private static SideChannelManager sSideChannelManager;

    /** Get a {@link NotificationManagerCompat} instance for a provided context. */
    public static NotificationManagerCompat from(Context context) {
        return new NotificationManagerCompat(context);
    }

    private NotificationManagerCompat(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    private static final Impl IMPL;

    interface Impl {
        void cancelNotification(NotificationManager notificationManager, String tag, int id);

        void postNotification(NotificationManager notificationManager, String tag, int id,
                Notification notification);

        int getSideChannelBindFlags();
    }

    static class ImplBase implements Impl {
        @Override
        public void cancelNotification(NotificationManager notificationManager, String tag,
                int id) {
            notificationManager.cancel(id);
        }

        @Override
        public void postNotification(NotificationManager notificationManager, String tag, int id,
                Notification notification) {
            notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
        }

        @Override
        public int getSideChannelBindFlags() {
            return Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE;
        }
    }

    static class ImplEclair extends ImplBase {
        @Override
        public void cancelNotification(NotificationManager notificationManager, String tag,
                int id) {
            NotificationManagerCompatEclair.cancelNotification(notificationManager, tag, id);
        }

        @Override
        public void postNotification(NotificationManager notificationManager, String tag, int id,
                Notification notification) {
            NotificationManagerCompatEclair.postNotification(notificationManager, tag, id,
                    notification);
        }
    }

    static class ImplIceCreamSandwich extends ImplEclair {
        @Override
        public int getSideChannelBindFlags() {
            return NotificationManagerCompatIceCreamSandwich.SIDE_CHANNEL_BIND_FLAGS;
        }
    }

    static {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            IMPL = new ImplIceCreamSandwich();
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 5) {
            IMPL = new ImplEclair();
        } else {
            IMPL = new ImplBase();
        }
        SIDE_CHANNEL_BIND_FLAGS = IMPL.getSideChannelBindFlags();
    }

    /**
     * Cancel a previously shown notification.
     * @param id the ID of the notification
     */
    public void cancel(int id) {
        cancel(null, id);
    }

    /**
     * Cancel a previously shown notification.
     * @param tag the string identifier of the notification.
     * @param id the ID of the notification
     */
    public void cancel(String tag, int id) {
        IMPL.cancelNotification(mNotificationManager, tag, id);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= MAX_SIDE_CHANNEL_SDK_VERSION) {
            pushSideChannelQueue(new CancelTask(mContext.getPackageName(), id, tag));
        }
    }

    /** Cancel all previously shown notifications. */
    public void cancelAll() {
        mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= MAX_SIDE_CHANNEL_SDK_VERSION) {
            pushSideChannelQueue(new CancelTask(mContext.getPackageName()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Post a notification to be shown in the status bar, stream, etc.
     * @param id the ID of the notification
     * @param notification the notification to post to the system
     */
    public void notify(int id, Notification notification) {
        notify(null, id, notification);
    }

    /**
     * Post a notification to be shown in the status bar, stream, etc.
     * @param tag the string identifier for a notification. Can be {@code null}.
     * @param id the ID of the notification. The pair (tag, id) must be unique within your app.
     * @param notification the notification to post to the system
    */
    public void notify(String tag, int id, Notification notification) {
        if (useSideChannelForNotification(notification)) {
            pushSideChannelQueue(new NotifyTask(mContext.getPackageName(), id, tag, notification));
            // Cancel this notification in notification manager if it just transitioned to being
            // side channelled.
            IMPL.cancelNotification(mNotificationManager, tag, id);
        } else {
            IMPL.postNotification(mNotificationManager, tag, id, notification);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the set of packages that have an enabled notification listener component within them.
     */
    public static Set<String> getEnabledListenerPackages(Context context) {
        final String enabledNotificationListeners = Settings.Secure.getString(
                context.getContentResolver(),
                SETTING_ENABLED_NOTIFICATION_LISTENERS);
        // Parse the string again if it is different from the last time this method was called.
        if (enabledNotificationListeners != null
                && !enabledNotificationListeners.equals(sEnabledNotificationListeners)) {
            final String[] components = enabledNotificationListeners.split(":");
            Set<String> packageNames = new HashSet<String>(components.length);
            for (String component : components) {
                ComponentName componentName = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(component);
                if (componentName != null) {
                    packageNames.add(componentName.getPackageName());
                }
            }
            synchronized (sEnabledNotificationListenersLock) {
                sEnabledNotificationListenerPackages = packageNames;
                sEnabledNotificationListeners = enabledNotificationListeners;
            }
        }
        return sEnabledNotificationListenerPackages;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this notification should use the side channel for delivery.
     */
    private static boolean useSideChannelForNotification(Notification notification) {
        Bundle extras = NotificationCompat.getExtras(notification);
        return extras != null && extras.getBoolean(EXTRA_USE_SIDE_CHANNEL);
    }

    /**
     * Push a notification task for distribution to notification side channels.
     */
    private void pushSideChannelQueue(Task task) {
        synchronized (sLock) {
            if (sSideChannelManager == null) {
                sSideChannelManager = new SideChannelManager(mContext.getApplicationContext());
            }
        }
        sSideChannelManager.queueTask(task);
    }

    /**
     * Helper class to manage a queue of pending tasks to send to notification side channel
     * listeners.
     */
    private static class SideChannelManager implements Handler.Callback, ServiceConnection {
        private static final int MSG_QUEUE_TASK = 0;
        private static final int MSG_SERVICE_CONNECTED = 1;
        private static final int MSG_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED = 2;
        private static final int MSG_RETRY_LISTENER_QUEUE = 3;

        private static final String KEY_BINDER = "binder";

        private final Context mContext;
        private final HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
        private final Handler mHandler;
        private final Map<ComponentName, ListenerRecord> mRecordMap =
                new HashMap<ComponentName, ListenerRecord>();
        private Set<String> mCachedEnabledPackages = new HashSet<String>();

        public SideChannelManager(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
            mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("NotificationManagerCompat");
            mHandlerThread.start();
            mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper(), this);
        }

        /**
         * Queue a new task to be sent to all listeners. This function can be called
         * from any thread.
         */
        public void queueTask(Task task) {
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_QUEUE_TASK, task).sendToTarget();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_QUEUE_TASK:
                    handleQueueTask((Task) msg.obj);
                    return true;
                case MSG_SERVICE_CONNECTED:
                    ServiceConnectedEvent event = (ServiceConnectedEvent) msg.obj;
                    handleServiceConnected(event.componentName, event.iBinder);
                    return true;
                case MSG_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED:
                    handleServiceDisconnected((ComponentName) msg.obj);
                    return true;
                case MSG_RETRY_LISTENER_QUEUE:
                    handleRetryListenerQueue((ComponentName) msg.obj);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void handleQueueTask(Task task) {
            updateListenerMap();
            for (ListenerRecord record : mRecordMap.values()) {
                record.taskQueue.add(task);
                processListenerQueue(record);
            }
        }

        private void handleServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            ListenerRecord record = mRecordMap.get(componentName);
            if (record != null) {
                record.service = INotificationSideChannel.Stub.asInterface(iBinder);
                record.retryCount = 0;
                processListenerQueue(record);
            }
        }

        private void handleServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            ListenerRecord record = mRecordMap.get(componentName);
            if (record != null) {
                ensureServiceUnbound(record);
            }
        }

        private void handleRetryListenerQueue(ComponentName componentName) {
            ListenerRecord record = mRecordMap.get(componentName);
            if (record != null) {
                processListenerQueue(record);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connected to service " + componentName);
            }
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_SERVICE_CONNECTED,
                    new ServiceConnectedEvent(componentName, iBinder))
                    .sendToTarget();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected from service " + componentName);
            }
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED, componentName).sendToTarget();
        }

        /**
         * Check the current list of enabled listener packages and update the records map
         * accordingly.
         */
        private void updateListenerMap() {
            Set<String> enabledPackages = getEnabledListenerPackages(mContext);
            if (enabledPackages.equals(mCachedEnabledPackages)) {
                // Short-circuit when the list of enabled packages has not changed.
                return;
            }
            mCachedEnabledPackages = enabledPackages;
            List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(
                    new Intent().setAction(ACTION_BIND_SIDE_CHANNEL), PackageManager.GET_SERVICES);
            Set<ComponentName> enabledComponents = new HashSet<ComponentName>();
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos) {
                if (!enabledPackages.contains(resolveInfo.serviceInfo.packageName)) {
                    continue;
                }
                ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
                        resolveInfo.serviceInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.serviceInfo.name);
                if (resolveInfo.serviceInfo.permission != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Permission present on component " + componentName
                            + ", not adding listener record.");
                    continue;
                }
                enabledComponents.add(componentName);
            }
            // Ensure all enabled components have a record in the listener map.
            for (ComponentName componentName : enabledComponents) {
                if (!mRecordMap.containsKey(componentName)) {
                    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Adding listener record for " + componentName);
                    }
                    mRecordMap.put(componentName, new ListenerRecord(componentName));
                }
            }
            // Remove listener records that are no longer for enabled components.
            Iterator<Map.Entry<ComponentName, ListenerRecord>> it =
                    mRecordMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<ComponentName, ListenerRecord> entry = it.next();
                if (!enabledComponents.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Removing listener record for " + entry.getKey());
                    }
                    ensureServiceUnbound(entry.getValue());
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Ensure we are already attempting to bind to a service, or start a new binding if not.
         * @return Whether the service bind attempt was successful.
         */
        private boolean ensureServiceBound(ListenerRecord record) {
            if (record.bound) {
                return true;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BIND_SIDE_CHANNEL).setComponent(record.componentName);
            record.bound = mContext.bindService(intent, this, SIDE_CHANNEL_BIND_FLAGS);
            if (record.bound) {
                record.retryCount = 0;
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unable to bind to listener " + record.componentName);
                mContext.unbindService(this);
            }
            return record.bound;
        }

        /**
         * Ensure we have unbound from a service.
         */
        private void ensureServiceUnbound(ListenerRecord record) {
            if (record.bound) {
                mContext.unbindService(this);
                record.bound = false;
            }
            record.service = null;
        }

        /**
         * Schedule a delayed retry to communicate with a listener service.
         * After a maximum number of attempts (with exponential back-off), start
         * dropping pending tasks for this listener.
         */
        private void scheduleListenerRetry(ListenerRecord record) {
            if (mHandler.hasMessages(MSG_RETRY_LISTENER_QUEUE, record.componentName)) {
                return;
            }
            record.retryCount++;
            if (record.retryCount > SIDE_CHANNEL_RETRY_MAX_COUNT) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Giving up on delivering " + record.taskQueue.size() + " tasks to "
                        + record.componentName + " after " + record.retryCount + " retries");
                record.taskQueue.clear();
                return;
            }
            int delayMs = SIDE_CHANNEL_RETRY_BASE_INTERVAL_MS * (1 << (record.retryCount - 1));
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Scheduling retry for " + delayMs + " ms");
            }
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_RETRY_LISTENER_QUEUE, record.componentName);
            mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, delayMs);
        }

        /**
         * Perform a processing step for a listener. First check the bind state, then attempt
         * to flush the task queue, and if an error is encountered, schedule a retry.
         */
        private void processListenerQueue(ListenerRecord record) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Processing component " + record.componentName + ", "
                        + record.taskQueue.size() + " queued tasks");
            }
            if (record.taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            if (!ensureServiceBound(record) || record.service == null) {
                // Ensure bind has started and that a service interface is ready to use.
                scheduleListenerRetry(record);
                return;
            }
            // Attempt to flush all items in the task queue.
            while (true) {
                Task task = record.taskQueue.peek();
                if (task == null) {
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Sending task " + task);
                    }
                    task.send(record.service);
                    record.taskQueue.remove();
                } catch (DeadObjectException e) {
                    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Remote service has died: " + record.componentName);
                    }
                    break;
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "RemoteException communicating with " + record.componentName, e);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!record.taskQueue.isEmpty()) {
                // Some tasks were not sent, meaning an error was encountered, schedule a retry.
                scheduleListenerRetry(record);
            }
        }

        /** A per-side-channel-service listener state record */
        private static class ListenerRecord {
            public final ComponentName componentName;
            /** Whether the service is currently bound to. */
            public boolean bound = false;
            /** The service stub provided by onServiceConnected */
            public INotificationSideChannel service;
            /** Queue of pending tasks to send to this listener service */
            public LinkedList<Task> taskQueue = new LinkedList<Task>();
            /** Number of retries attempted while connecting to this listener service */
            public int retryCount = 0;

            public ListenerRecord(ComponentName componentName) {
                this.componentName = componentName;
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ServiceConnectedEvent {
        final ComponentName componentName;
        final IBinder iBinder;

        public ServiceConnectedEvent(ComponentName componentName,
                final IBinder iBinder) {
            this.componentName = componentName;
            this.iBinder = iBinder;
        }
    }

    private interface Task {
        public void send(INotificationSideChannel service) throws RemoteException;
    }

    private static class NotifyTask implements Task {
        final String packageName;
        final int id;
        final String tag;
        final Notification notif;

        public NotifyTask(String packageName, int id, String tag, Notification notif) {
            this.packageName = packageName;
            this.id = id;
            this.tag = tag;
            this.notif = notif;
        }

        @Override
        public void send(INotificationSideChannel service) throws RemoteException {
            service.notify(packageName, id, tag, notif);
        }

        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("NotifyTask[");
            sb.append("packageName:").append(packageName);
            sb.append(", id:").append(id);
            sb.append(", tag:").append(tag);
            sb.append("]");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    private static class CancelTask implements Task {
        final String packageName;
        final int id;
        final String tag;
        final boolean all;

        public CancelTask(String packageName) {
            this.packageName = packageName;
            this.id = 0;
            this.tag = null;
            this.all = true;
        }

        public CancelTask(String packageName, int id, String tag) {
            this.packageName = packageName;
            this.id = id;
            this.tag = tag;
            this.all = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void send(INotificationSideChannel service) throws RemoteException {
            if (all) {
                service.cancelAll(packageName);
            } else {
                service.cancel(packageName, id, tag);
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("CancelTask[");
            sb.append("packageName:").append(packageName);
            sb.append(", id:").append(id);
            sb.append(", tag:").append(tag);
            sb.append(", all:").append(all);
            sb.append("]");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try this import android.support.v7.app.NotificationManagerCompat

Comment: I can be wrong, but I think, that these methods are available from Android N SDK

Comment: sorry what does that mean and how do I get Android N SDK?

Comment: If you've got the absolutely latest version of the support library, and those methods still don't resolve, then apparently they haven't actually released that yet. You're not the first who's been asking about that, and apparently they prematurely released the docs and revision history for those methods. AFAIK, anyway. Which version do you have?

Comment: Raj, if i wrote that import it underlines it in red and wont compile

Comment: I thought the questions were different enough, the first question asked why something wasnt working, the second one was why public methods of a class were missing.

Comment: Eh, it's a fine line, I suppose. The answer would've been the same on your other one, though, after you fixed your calling semantics.

Comment: Yeh i understand if i should have rather just updated that one.

Comment: No biggie. Anyhoo, those methods are (supposed to be) in [version 24.0.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html). Last I saw, it wasn't available just yet, but that's been a minute, so just double-check and make sure you've got the latest.